# Demonstrably wrong answer plagiarized from my correct one

Tags: discussion

Someone posted a wrong answer, which was factually wrong. I wrote a correct answer. The wrong answer guy copied my right answer to correct his.  this is the edit.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/24828/4

Comment: Similar to [this discussion?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2861/1696) Incorporating information from other answers isn't always frowned upon, and it appears that the copied section is a published regulation which should be fair game. It also appears the answer has since been edited to credit you for first posting said regulation.

Comment: this isn't a case where a user "continuously edits his response to include the gist of later answers." Its  a case where OP said "yes you need another checkride", then changes it to "no, you don't need another checkride".

Comment: he added an (incorrect) attribution after I scolded him

Comment: So he only edited it once, which should be even more acceptable than editing it many times.

Comment: [doffs mod hat] I personally tend to delete my answers when I'm way off base or just flat out wrong, and someone else is right. [dons mod hat] I'm taking a look at how this went down, and I'll mull it over.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I took a pass through the revision history and looked at the two answers on their own as well. I can see why you're frustrated.

However, there are a few extenuating circumstances here.

1. It's a two-part answer to a two-part question.
2. You yourself are the person who pointed out that his initial answer was wrong.

   - Technically, only half of his answer was wrong!
3. He recognized the first part of his answer was wrong, and corrected it, citing 61.63.

Now, I have a hard time agreeing that he actually plagiarized your answer. He certainly used your knowledge to improve his own answer. However, he did already have a fully-formed answer to the other half of the question as well, and it is correct.

What should he have done instead? Would you be happier had he deleted the entire answer? Should he have left it as it originally was – partially incorrect?

I think given the circumstances, there's nothing particularly wrong with what happened here. It's hard to have a lot of variety in answers involving the FARs.